# read epub file page by page using epublib

Tags: java, android, epub, epublib

i'm working on an application in which i want to read epub file page by page using epublib and  show in a app , i am able to get all contents of book chapter wise  , now i want to get contents page wise , plz answer if you have any idea , thanks in advance

here is code that i used for getting contents of book chapter wise

```
    public String getText(String filepath) {

    String linez = "";
    File f = new File(filepath);

    InputStream epubInputStream = null;
    try {
        epubInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    Book book = null;
    try {
        book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Spine spine = book.getSpine();
    List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences();
    int count = spineList.size();
    txtpages.setText("Size:" + Integer.toString(count) + "\n");
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

        try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    linez = string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // do something with stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //webView.loadData(linez, "text/html", "utf-8");


    return linez;
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "now i want to get contents page wise". Do you mean that you want to paginate each XHTML file of the <spine> of your EPUB? If so, you need to inject your own CSS and load CSS+XHTML into the WebView, or you need to split the XHTML contents within your Java code.

Comment: yes i want to paginate each xhtml

Comment: were you able to find an answer how to paginate it.

Comment: @ArunavhKrishnan Krishnan i didn't find the solution

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41122252/7235539

Answer (score 0):

You may able to seperate an epub file page by page by using [EpubParser](https://github.com/mertakdut/EpubParser). Even though it still has some issues it does its job.